# cassandra list index out of range while importing data using COPY command in CQL

Tags: import, cassandra, cql

I am trying to import 1 million records into cassandra table.

It inserted 200000 rows and then aborted the process showing this error:

> Processed 200000 rows; Write: 2414.08 rows/s
>   list index out of range
>   Aborting import at record #204264. Previously inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be present as well.

Comment: maybe you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529813/cassandra-copy-command-connection-heartbeat-failure

Comment: I am running the one import at a time. I think its some error related with list index out of range.

Comment: Is there a data type error @ record number 204264? How many total records were imported? How many did you expect to be imported?

Comment: There seems no error #204264. Its like any other records. It say 200000 records processed. Also the select count(*) from tablename throws timeout error. So I m not sure how many records are actually inserted.